# Numpy.dot matrix multiplication: (n-by-m)*(m-by-k) and (m-by-k)*(k-by-n) have very different speeds

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have the following Python code:

```
import numpy
import time

A = numpy.random.random((10,60000))
B = numpy.random.random((60000,785))
C = numpy.random.random((785,10))

t = time.time()
D = A.dot(B)
print "%.2f s" % (time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
E = B.dot(C)
print "%.2f s" % (time.time() - t)
```

I think the two matrix multiplications A * B and B * C should take approximately the same amount of time, because both multiplications involve 10 * 60000 * 785 multiplication operations.

However, on different machines I got very different timings. On my laptop (Windows 7, 2.40 GHz CPU, 8G memory, Python 2.7, Numpy 1.7.1), I got:

```
0.21 s
0.21 s
```

which is normal. On a cluster machine (Linux CentOS 5.6, 2.66 GHz CPU, 16G memory, Python 2.7.3, Numpy 1.8.1), I got:

```
6.77 s
1.10 s
```

where A * B is much slower than B * C.

Can anyone explain why the two multiplications take different amounts of time?
I'm not sure what configurations are relevant, but I'll try to provide whatever information necessary.

Comment: Is `numpy.transpose(B).dot(numpy.transpose(A))` much slower than `B*C` as well? If not, I suspect this is a memory layout issue.

Comment: Note that the differences between machines may be due to different BLAS libraries.  I'm betting that your CentOS numpy isn't linked against a "full" BLAS library and is using numpy's builtin (but slow) BLAS-subtitute.  Have a look a the output of `numpy.show_config()` on both systems to compare.

Comment: @JoeKington The configs are indeed different. On Windows I have the following: blas_opt_info (libraries: f77blas, cblas, atlas, language: c), lapack_opt_info (libraries: lapack, f77blas, cblas, atlas, language: f77), atlas_info (libraries: lapack, f77blas, cblas, atlas, language: f77), atlas_blas_info (libraries: f77blas, cblas, atlas, language: c). On Linux I have: blas_info (libraries: blas, language: f77), lapack_info (libraries: lapack, language: f77), blas_opt_info (libraries: blas, language: f77), lapack_opt_info (libraries: lapack, blas, language: f77).

Comment: @JoeKington Sorry for the long list, but the configs differ a lot. Is this causing the different speeds?

Comment: @Magio - Well, the Linux version of numpy isn't linked against an Atlas or MKL version of BLAS or LAPACK, so that explains the much slower speeds overall.  Is there a chance you could try installing Anaconda's python (it will install in your home directory or anywhere you have write permission) and re-test the timings with a fully-linked version of numpy?

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks! I just installed Anaconda's Python, and the timings I get now are: A * B: 0.22s; B' * A': 0.22s; B * C: 0.27s; C' * B': 0.27s. I think this is normal :)

Answer (score 0):

There are more elements in A than C, so the results are intuitive.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The time complexity of multiplying an n-by-m matrix and an m-by-k matrix is O(nmk). Also, the fact that I get different timings on different machines suggest that it may have something to do with configurations.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for comment, not an answer)

If you run the following, do you get wide differences in performance?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4                                                                 
import numpy
import time

A = numpy.random.random((10,60000))
B = numpy.random.random((60000,785))
C = numpy.random.random((785,10))

t = time.time()
D = A.dot(B)
print("%.2f s" % (time.time() - t))

t = time.time()
D = numpy.transpose(B).dot(numpy.transpose(A))
print("%.2f s" % (time.time() - t))

t = time.time()
D = B.dot(C)
print("%.2f s" % (time.time() - t))

t = time.time()
D = numpy.transpose(C).dot(numpy.transpose(B))
print("%.2f s" % (time.time() - t))
```

When I run this, I obtain

```
0.21 s
0.22 s
0.44 s
0.22 s
```

This is strongly indicative of memory access pattern differences.

Comment: I got interesting patterns:
On Windows: 0.20s, 1.15s, 0.20s, 1.16s;
On Linux: 6.82s, 6.79s, 1.10s, 1.31s.

Comment: I just installed Anaconda's Python according to @JoeKington's comment, and now I get 0.22s, 0.22s, 0.27s, 0.27s. This seems to be normal. Thanks!